# Inner for loop working - outer loop incorrect?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, iteration

I managed to advance with a problem I was having and am looking for advice on the structure of my outer for loop. My inner loop works correctly. I want to repeat the 11 calculations 6 times using a different height (value of h) for each iteration. On the iterations of the J loop h increases to it's original value + 2*h. POI in the K loop depends on h and is defined but has been omitted for readability. Can update with the full script if necessary. Should the definition of POI be within the nested loop?

```
h = 0.5985;
GroundDistance = 18.75;
SouthAngle = 57;
TreeHeight = 14;
POI = TreeHeight-h;
BuildingElevationAng = atand(POI/GroundDistance);
a=0.265;
TreeLengthRHS = 15.89+a;
h = 0.5985;

    X(1,1)=h;
    for k = 2:6;
      X(k) = X(k-1) + (X(1)*2);
    end

for J = 1:6
  h=h+(2*h);
     for K  = 1:11
       TreeLengthTest(K) = TreeLengthRHS + (2*(K-1)*a);
       TreeLengthLHS = 75 - TreeLengthTest(K);
       AngleBx(K) = atand(TreeLengthLHS/GroundDistance);
       AngleCx(K) = atand(TreeLengthTest(K)/GroundDistance); %wasTreeLengthRHS
       DistanceAx(K) = GroundDistance/cosd(SouthAngle);
       DistanceBx(K) = GroundDistance/cosd(AngleBx(K));
       DistanceCx(K) = GroundDistance/cosd(AngleCx(K));
       AltAngleA(K) = atand(POI/DistanceAx(K));
       AltAngleB(K) = atand(POI/DistanceBx(K));
       AltAngleC(K) = atand(POI/DistanceCx(K));
       AzimuthA = 0;
       AzimuthB = (-AngleBx)-SouthAngle;
       AzimuthC = AngleCx-SouthAngle;
       end
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Neither h nor J are used within the loop, what is the purpose of repeating it?

Comment: I've scaled the script back for readability but POI is a variable defined in terms of h. I will update the post to include the full script. This may demonstrate clearer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: "Should it be within the nested loop?" What is "it"? I'm unclear what you're asking

Comment: I'm wondering if the definition of POI has to be in the nested loop or if it can remain outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a couple things I'm not sure of, but I'll give a shot at an answer, and see if this helps. The definition of POI does not have to be inside the inner loop, because POI is constant for each of those 11 calculations. However, I think you're defining `h` a little bit incorrectly, because you'll never get to use the value of `h` that you define initially. Since you already have the `X` vector, what if you try your nested for loops like:

```
for J = 1:6
    POI = TreeHeight - X(J);
    for K = 1:11
        ...All your code here...
    end
end
```